# IDE Module for Hand Drawing?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, mono

I'm currently looking for **a hand drawing (2D) library/module** (that would be like Paint, Paint.Net or Photoshop - but I don't need all the power of Photoshop...) that would allow me to add a drawing module to an IDE application.

That application is in it's early design phase : for instance I'm only estimating if I will be able to work on it on my spare time. I'm thinking to use **C#/Mono** or **C++/QT** as the IDE framework but it's not decided yet. That application would be open-source.

**A separate module to handle the drawing part** would be a good thing - allowing me to concentrate on the other important feature of the application, instead of implementing it myself. That module would be instantiated by the user to create or edit an image (no need for Photoshop power). That image would then be manipulated by the application (with other data).

I've been searching in Google, Sourceforge and code.google.com for hours but couldn't find something like that in C# or C++/QT - only drawing by code libraries. Maybe I'm not searching right... Anyway, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will need to create a module for drawing.

I have done some drawing utilities using QGraphicsView from Qt >4.3 and it's pretty easy. I will consider it.

Good luck! :D

Comment: I fear I'll have to do that...
I don't really understand : there are a lot of web software modules/library to do that but nothing for non-web software O__o...

Comment: Go step by step, the Qt documentation is great in a few days you will understand all the QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene framework

Answer (score 0):

well, are you looking for something like a control library or an active x control which you can just plug in to your app ?.

I am not sure if you would like to accept a commercial software, but here is few

http://drawing-activex.qarchive.org/

Honestly I didn't search much; but you need to search for a activex or a control library

Comment: Yes I need a control library or a separate module (a separate window or something like that). But it have to be cross-platform and open-source compatible...